# freopen doesn't work for C stdin

Tags: c++, binary, stdin, mingw32, wine

While executing the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <cstdio>
/* stdin
   stdout
   FILE
   freopen */

int main() {
    for (FILE* f : {stdin, stdout})
        if (nullptr == freopen(nullptr, (f == stdin) ? "rb" : "wb", f))
            cout << f << '\n';
}
```

... I get the following output:

```
0x7edde180
```

... which means that `freopen(nullptr, "rb", stdin)` returned `nullptr`, failing.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Compiler: `i586-mingw32msvc-g++` on the GNU OS

Environment: wine (x86)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you conclude that `0x7edde180` is `stdin` and not `stdout`?

Comment: `freopen()` is for re-opening files. It expects a file name: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/

Comment: @Galik: a `NULL` filename is a perfectly acceptable value (as indicated by the page you linked to).

Comment: Check `errno`, you'll never know why it fails otherwise. (Implementations are free to fail that call for whatever reason.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk2h68td.aspx

> If path, mode, or stream is a null pointer, or if filename is an empty string, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions set errno to EINVAL and return NULL.

In short, it looks like the MSVC++ implementation of freopen does not allow for a NULL pathname.

Comment: In short, it looks like the MSVC++ implementation of freopen doesn't meet the ISO C++ standard. `-.-"`

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrowitschKlim: Sorry, but the C++ standard says nothing about these functions, except that they're standard in C.  And the C standard says "It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are permitted (if any), and under what circumstances." So an implementation which forbids all changes of mode, is completely compliant.

Comment: @BenVoigt: So there isn't any guarantee to be able to read binary data from cstdio, right?

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrowitschKlim: There isn't any guarantee to be able to read binary data from a `FILE*` which was originally opened in text mode.  Of course you can open it in the right mode to begin with.

Comment: Then `freopen(NULL, <originalmode>, f)` should work always as no mode change is performed, but on MSVC it doesn't.